# How do I change the text: Click on Event Name for description/registration

Tags: plugins

I am running Event Registration for the first time on a WP site and would like to be able to edit the phrase that shows up at the beginning of the Event Registration page:

> Click on Event Name for description/registration

I have searched all the templates but I can't find where that is located. Any assistance in finding that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a link to the plugin but I guess you mean [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/event-registration/).

I wonder if you mean:

- line [#20](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/event-registration/tags/6.00.31/public/evr_public-show_event_list.php#L20) in the file `/public/evr_public-show_event_list.php`:

  ```
  echo '<caption>'.__('Click on Event Name for description/registration','evr_language').'</caption>';
  ```
- line [#338](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/event-registration/tags/6.00.31/evr_content.php#L338) in the file `evr_content.php`:

  ```
  <b>Click on Event Name for description/registration</b>
  ```

You could use the [`gettext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter to change the former, but you should report the latter one to the plugin author and ask for a proper localization of that text.

Comment: Brilliant. Yes, you not only got the right plugin but the correct line as well. Well done.

Comment: Glad to hear that. This plugin is using `109` php files and  `452` files in total, no wonder it's hard to find stuff in there ;-)